# reading log files in Python and outputing specific text

Tags: python, logging, loops

I have a piece of code that reads the last line of a log file as the log is being written to. I want to print errors which occur in the logs, basically start printing when `line.startswith('Error')` and finish printing when `line.startwith('End of Error')`. My code is below, Could anybody help me with this please?

```
log = 'C:\mylog.log'
file = open(log, 'r')
res = os.stat(log)
size = res[6]
file.seek(size)

while 1:
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(1)
        file.seek(where)
    else:
        if line.startswith('Error'):
        #print lines until you come to 'End of Error'
```

Comment: what does not work for the moment ? where is the error ? what do you get when running your script and what did you expect ?

Comment: After the line "if line.startswith('Error')", here I want to insert some code that will output line, untill it gets to 'End of Error'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a flag before the loop:

```
in_error = False
```

Then switch it on and off as needed:

```
if line.startswith('Error'):
    in_error = True
elif line.startswith('End of Error'):
    print(line)
    in_error = False
if in_error:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to simply run `tail -F` (capital F, available on GNU platforms) and process the output.

Comment: `subprocess` not `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Agreed, or even consider simply piping the output to stdin of your python process. `tail -f <file> | <parser>.py`. Of course, based on your log file location, it looks like your platform is Windows.